# Align child to top of inline parent in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, vertical-alignment

I want to align an element to the top of the enclosing inline element. Therefore I'm using this code:

HTML:

```
<span id="outer">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <span id="inner">Watch me align!</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
    position: relative;
}

#inner {    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This code works in Firefox and Chrome: The text is positioned in the top-left corner of the image. But in Internet Explorer the text sticks to the bottom of the image.

You can see this in [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9pEb/2/).

After reading [this MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I conclude that the vertical-align property doesn't apply on inline elements since they don't support the valign attribute.

My best idea by now is to reposition the text using some JavaScript, but as you may agree: That's no elegant solution.

So, do you know any neat trick to make this work in Internet Explorer?

IMPORTANT! The following CSS properties of the parent can't be changed:

```
#outer {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, guys! But I need a real inline element, no inline-block. Sorry, I should've been more precise on that! (Background: If I use any other display value, the images won't stick together on a resize. [Try out here!](http://jsfiddle.net/K9pEb/4/))

Answer (score 0):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/gcG4D/

HTML

```
<span id="outer">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <span id="inner">Watch me align!</span>
</span>
```

CSS

```
#outer {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
}

#inner {    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    display:block;
}

img {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger layout to span with

- `float` `left` or `right` or
- `display` `inline-block` , `table`, `inline-table`, `block` ... but
  `inline` or
- `position` `fixed` or `absolute` or

http://jsfiddle.net/K9pEb/3/

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: inline-block;` to your `#outer` class. It should fix your issue in IE.